# Laravel seeding pivot table - how to avoid duplication?

Tags: php, laravel, duplicates, seed

Hy guys!

I would just like to find out if there is an easy way to avoid duplication's when seeding a pivot table.

I have these two tables:

**category**

**post**

and a pivot table:

**category_post**

I can seed them, and it works, my relations are working two.

Everything works, except the fact that i have posts that belong to multiple categories.

So i want a **post to belong to only one categore**, categories of course have more posts.

This is how my category_post_seed file looks like:

```
class CategoryPostTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        $categoryIds = Category::lists('id');
        $postIds = Post::lists('id');

        foreach(range(1, 50) as $index)
        {
            DB::table('category_post')->insert([
               'category_id' => $faker->randomElement($categoryIds),
               'post_id' => $faker->randomElement($postIds)
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you want that if you have many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @deczo i don't think i want/have many-to-man relationship, but i may be wrong. Could you elaborate? Right now i want one post to belong to only one category, but a category has a lot of posts. Is that many-to-man?

Comment: Many-to-many is a relation that you define with pivot table usualy, so you can link many posts to many categories. Otherwise you need one-to-many relation, which is, in the context of Eloquent, `Category` has many `Post`, and `Post` belongs to `Category`. Then there is a foreign key on the `posts` table that links to the primary key of the `categories` table, thus you won't be able to make one `Post` belong to many `Category`, which you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sync()` which will remove all the rows from the pivot table for a certain post/category and then add a row for each item in the array.  In this case, you'd only give it one item.

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$category->posts()->sync(array($somePostID));

    $faker = Faker::create();

    $categoryIds = Category::lists('id');
    $postIds = Post::lists('id');

    foreach(range(1, 50) as $index)
    {
        $category = Category::find($faker->randomElement($categoryIds));
        $category->posts()->sync(array($faker->randomElement($postIDs)));
    }
```

Comment: i updated my question with my seed file, how can i accomplish what you said?

Comment: i tried it out, but the result was that: i have 30 posts, in my posts table, which is ok, i have 7 categories in my categories table, which is still ok, but i have only 7 rows in my category post pivot table, which is not ok. Was that suppose to happen?

Comment: Because you only have 7 categories.  If you wanted 1 post per category, obviously all you will have in your pivot table is 7 items.  Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks to @deczo i found out that my problem was that my relations are wrong i have one to many relation and not many to many, but to be honest your answer is a good solution for the question i posted, so thank you to.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, you had me pretty confused.